# Fixed Tabe Head with Scrollable Table Body

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I have to make this table content (tbody) with scroll bar & the height of the table is fixed. To enable scroll, i have added the style `display: block`. After that the width of the table is frozen and not adjustable. Find me a way to make the table width full.

[image: Currently the table looks like]

HTML :

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="item_table">
       <thead>
        <tr class="bg-primary">
         <th>#</th>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Unit Price</th>
          <th>Discount</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th><i class="fa fa-close"></i></th>
         </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="item_list">
     <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>Mens Full Sleeve Shirts</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2200.00</td>
       <td>200.00</td>
       <td>2000.00</td>
       <td><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS :

```
#item_table{
    display: table-row;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

#item_list{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    table-layout:fixed;
    height: 170px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't add `display:block` to a table. It will destroy it.

Wrap the table Insteed into a `div` and add  `overflow:auto` to this element.

Or if using bootstrap, add to the container the class `table-responsive` as you can see in the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/)

Comment: Its enables scroll for the whole table, i just need scroll only for the tbody.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try with this :

```
tbody {
    height: 100px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Work, Its sets the height but not enables the scroll bar.